# Track user activity in Dash application

Tags: python, plotly-dash, audit-trail

I have deployed a dash app to a computer (to act as a server) for which people in my company can access it if they're connected to the company network. I am also going to apply the basic dash-auth.

Is there anyway to track the IP address, username, password, and timestamp of when a user logs into the app and save this audit log information to a simple text file and keep updating over time?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?